# Function structure in java with generic

Tags: java, android, oop, generics

```
public static <X, Y> SomeClass<Y> functionName(
        @NonNull Class<X> source,
        @NonNull final Class<X, Y> mapFunction) {

    return result;
}
```

Please, can anyone describe the above function structures like a return type what?

Comment: You're asking for a return type of this function or...?

Comment: are you sure about `Class<X, Y> mapFunction`? this doesn't seem right, `Class` can get only one generic type

Comment: @PavelSmirnov yes I am asking for the return type of this function.

Comment: It's `SomeClass<Y>`.

Comment: Return type is in here SomeClass<Y> . <X> and <Y> are the generic variable you have to put them also before the return type. Please, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: @PavelSmirnov can you  describe then whats is mean of <X , Y> before the SomeClass<Y>

Comment: @Pawankumarsharma, it's bounded type parameters. You can read about it in the official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).